# Accessing Models Data from the View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this model

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

How to print the Name value in the View component?

Answer (score 0):

In your .cshtml file, add your Model by: `@model <YourSolution_name>.Models.Student`

And print it: `<p>Model.Name</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Specify model in view page and pass instance of model from controller method to view page. Following is an example of view page and controller.

**Controller Example**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVC_Net_Example.Controllers
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {   
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Student myStudent = new Student();
            myStudent.ID = 1;
            myStudent.Name = "Sylvester";
            myStudent.LastName = "Stallone";
            myStudent.Email = "sylvesterstallone@outlook.com";
            return View(myStudent);
        }
    }
}
```

Index View Page Example

```
@model MVC_Net_Example.Controllers.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Student Detail";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```